# Progress bar in a photoslider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a photo slider made by HTML+CSS+JS. Currently it has navigation arrows, dots, and autoplay function. The animation changes its direction according to the interaction with the corresponding arrows/dots, and it resets the timer on each click. I'm trying to improve it step by step, and currently into adding a progress bar that'll fill automatically based on `sliderSpeed`.

Could you please help?

```js
var timeout;

function setDirection(d) {
  document.querySelector('.slider').style.setProperty('--direction', d);
}
setDirection(1);
var slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slider")[0];
var sliderDots = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("dots")[0].children);
var sliderContents = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("elements")[0].children);
var sliderArrowLeft = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-left")[0];
var sliderArrowRight = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-right")[0];
var sliderSpeed = 4000,
  currentSlide = 0,
  currentActive = 0,
  sliderTimer = 0;

function playSlide(slide, d) {
  if (!(d === undefined)) {
    direction = d;
    setDirection(d);

    // Force it forwards after it's done:
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      setDirection(1);
    }, 1000)
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < sliderDots.length; k++) {
    sliderContents[k].classList.remove("active");
    sliderContents[k].classList.remove("inactive");
    sliderDots[k].classList.remove("active");
  }
  if (slide < 0) {
    slide = currentSlide = sliderContents.length - 1;
  }
  if (slide > sliderContents.length - 1) {
    slide = currentSlide = 0;
  }
  if (currentActive != currentSlide) {
    sliderContents[currentActive].classList.add("inactive");
  }
  sliderContents[slide].classList.add("active");
  sliderDots[slide].classList.add("active");
  currentActive = currentSlide;
  clearTimeout(sliderTimer);
  sliderTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    playSlide(currentSlide += 1);
  }, sliderSpeed)
}
sliderArrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  playSlide(currentSlide -= 1, -1);
})
sliderArrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  playSlide(currentSlide += 1, 1);
})
for (var l = 0; l < sliderDots.length; l++) {
  sliderDots[l].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let d = sliderDots.indexOf(this) - currentSlide
    playSlide(currentSlide = sliderDots.indexOf(this), Math.sign(d));
  })
}
playSlide(currentSlide);
```

```css
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.arrow-left,
.arrow-right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.arrow-left {
  left: 0;
}

.arrow-right {
  right: 0;
}

.dots {
  height: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.dot {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

.dot.active {
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.elements {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(0px);
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.image span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.image.active {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image.inactive {
  z-index: -3;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image.active span {
  animation: show .5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.image.inactive span {
  animation: hide .5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(calc(var(--direction)*100%));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(calc(-1*var(--direction)*100%));
  }
}

.bar-holder {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.bar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="arrow-left">prev</div>
    <div class="arrow-right">next</div>
    <div class="dots">
      <li class="dot"></li>
      <li class="dot"></li>
      <li class="dot"></li>
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <div class="image"><span>image 1</span></div>
      <div class="image"><span>image 2</span></div>
      <div class="image"><span>image 3</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar-holder">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited the code a lit bit.
Added a function to handle the progress bar. I am still fixing some code

```js
  function setDirection(d) {
    document.querySelector('.slider').style.setProperty('--direction', d);
  }
  setDirection(1);
var slideSpeed = 4000; //speed per slide
var currentSlide = 0;
var sliderTimer = 0;
var progressBarInterval = null; // Track the progress bar interval

var slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
var sliderContents = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
var numImages = sliderContents.length;
var totalDuration = slideSpeed * numImages; // Total duration for all slides

function updateProgressBar(progress) {
    const progressBar = document.querySelector(".bar");
    progressBar.style.width = progress + "%";
}

function animateProgressBar(progressStart, progressEnd, duration) {
    const interval = 10; // Update interval for smoother animation
    const steps = duration / interval;
    const increment = (progressEnd - progressStart) / steps;

    let currentProgress = progressStart;
    clearInterval(progressBarInterval); // Clear any previous progress bar interval

    progressBarInterval = setInterval(() => {
        currentProgress += increment;
        updateProgressBar(currentProgress);

        if ((increment > 0 && currentProgress >= progressEnd) || (increment < 0 && currentProgress <= progressEnd)) {
            clearInterval(progressBarInterval);
        }
    }, interval);
}

function calculateProgressBarDuration() {
    return totalDuration / numImages;
}

function playSlide(slide) {
    for (var k = 0; k < sliderContents.length; k++) {
        sliderContents[k].classList.remove("active");
    }
    if (slide < 0) {
        slide = currentSlide = numImages - 1;
    }
    if (slide >= numImages) {
        slide = currentSlide = 0;
    }
    sliderContents[slide].classList.add("active");
    currentSlide = slide;

    // Calculate progress values based on the current slide
    const progressStart = (currentSlide / numImages) * 100;
    const progressEnd = ((currentSlide + 1) / numImages) * 100;

    // Calculate the duration for the progress bar animation based on the total duration and the number of slides
    const progressDuration = calculateProgressBarDuration();

    // Start the progress bar animation with the calculated duration
    animateProgressBar(progressStart, progressEnd, progressDuration);

    // Set a timer to advance to the next slide
    clearTimeout(sliderTimer);
    sliderTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        playSlide(currentSlide + 1);
    }, progressDuration); // Adjusted timing
}

playSlide(currentSlide);

document.querySelector('.arrow-left').addEventListener("click", function () {
    playSlide(currentSlide - 1);
});

document.querySelector('.arrow-right').addEventListener("click", function () {
    playSlide(currentSlide + 1);
});

var dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');

dots.forEach(function (dot, index) {
    dot.addEventListener("click", function () {
        playSlide(index);
    });
});
```

```css
.slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

  .contents {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .arrow-left,
  .arrow-right {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  .arrow-left {
    left: 0;
  }

  .arrow-right {
    right: 0;
  }

  .dots {
    height: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

  .dot {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  }

  .dot.active {
    background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  }

  .elements {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translate(0px);
  }

  .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%; /* Start off-screen to the right */

  }

  .image span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  }

  .image.active {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .image.inactive {
    z-index: -3;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .image.active span {
    animation: show .5s ease-in-out forwards;
  }

  .image.inactive span {
    animation: hide .5s ease-in-out forwards;
  }

  @keyframes show {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(calc(var(--direction)*100%));
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }

  @keyframes hide {
    0% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(calc(-1*var(--direction)*100%));
    }
  }

  .bar-holder {
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  }

  .bar {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10px;
    background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="contents">
        <div class="arrow-left">prev</div>
        <div class="arrow-right">next</div>
        <div class="dots">
            <li class="dot"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
            <li class="dot"></li>
        </div>
        <div class="elements">
            <div class="image"><span>image 1</span></div>
            <div class="image"><span>image 2</span></div>
            <div class="image"><span>image 3</span></div>
            <div class="image"><span>image 4</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-holder">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Looks nice, but are you sure this function fills the bar according to the `sliderSpeed` value? I'm trying to fill the progress bar to display the remaining time of the **current** slider page... (BTW: Please add a code snippet, so it'll be easier for everyone to see how it functions). Thanks!

Comment: I edited the code and provided a snippet, but its still a lil bit buggy. But i am trying to fix it

Comment: Thank you, seems much better. But as mentioned, your progress bar indicates the total duration of all four slides. My goal is making a progress bar that indicates the durations of each slides

Comment: I updated the code for you

Comment: Seems nice. Fyi, calculation is still based on the total, and the transition effects between the images are gone

Comment: The sliders are working, and yes i need the total duration the calculate the progres bar speed etc. but you can still set a speed per slide etc.

Comment: Inactive image animation is missing, dots don't indicate the active image any more, and sliding direction is always from right to left now... In my opinion, you should analyze the source codes again, and implement your method from scratch... When adding a new feature, I think it's important to avoid breaking the existing features. It may not be easy to fix them all later :)

Answer (score 0):

I edited your snipped such that it uses a CSS animation. The duration of the animation is set using javascript in the first line of your `playSlide()` function.
This uses the efficiency of the browsers css rendering engine.
I marked the lines that I changed with comments, e.g. `//====Line added====`

```js
var timeout;

function setDirection(d) {
  document.querySelector('.slider').style.setProperty('--direction', d);
}
setDirection(1);
var slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slider")[0];
var sliderDots = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("dots")[0].children);
var sliderContents = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("elements")[0].children);
var sliderArrowLeft = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-left")[0];
var sliderArrowRight = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-right")[0];
var sliderSpeed = 4000,
  currentSlide = 0,
  currentActive = 0,
  sliderTimer = 0;

function playSlide(slide, d) {
  //====Lines added====
 var progressIndicatorBar = document.querySelector('.bar'); 
 progressIndicatorBar.style.animationDuration = sliderSpeed + 'ms';
  progressIndicatorBar.classList.remove('bar');
  setTimeout(() => progressIndicatorBar.classList.add('bar'), 1);
  //====End of new lines====
  if (!(d === undefined)) {
    direction = d;
    setDirection(d);

    // Force it forwards after it's done:
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      setDirection(1);
    }, 1000)
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < sliderDots.length; k++) {
    sliderContents[k].classList.remove("active");
    sliderContents[k].classList.remove("inactive");
    sliderDots[k].classList.remove("active");
  }
  if (slide < 0) {
    slide = currentSlide = sliderContents.length - 1;
  }
  if (slide > sliderContents.length - 1) {
    slide = currentSlide = 0;
  }
  if (currentActive != currentSlide) {
    sliderContents[currentActive].classList.add("inactive");
  }
  sliderContents[slide].classList.add("active");
  sliderDots[slide].classList.add("active");
  currentActive = currentSlide;
  clearTimeout(sliderTimer);
  sliderTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    playSlide(currentSlide += 1);
  }, sliderSpeed)
}
sliderArrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  playSlide(currentSlide -= 1, -1);
})
sliderArrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  playSlide(currentSlide += 1, 1);
})
for (var l = 0; l < sliderDots.length; l++) {
  sliderDots[l].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let d = sliderDots.indexOf(this) - currentSlide
    playSlide(currentSlide = sliderDots.indexOf(this), Math.sign(d));
  })
}
playSlide(currentSlide);
```

```css
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.arrow-left,
.arrow-right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.arrow-left {
  left: 0;
}

.arrow-right {
  right: 0;
}

.dots {
  height: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.dot {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

.dot.active {
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.elements {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(0px);
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.image span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.image.active {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image.inactive {
  z-index: -3;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image.active span {
  animation: show .5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.image.inactive span {
  animation: hide .5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(calc(var(--direction)*100%));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(calc(-1*var(--direction)*100%));
  }
}

.bar-holder {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.bar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgb(255,0,0);
  /*====Line added====*/
  animation: progress-indicator infinite linear;
}
/*====Animation added====*/
@keyframes progress-indicator {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="arrow-left">prev</div>
    <div class="arrow-right">next</div>
    <div class="dots">
      <li class="dot"></li>
      <li class="dot"></li>
      <li class="dot"></li>
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <div class="image"><span>image 1</span></div>
      <div class="image"><span>image 2</span></div>
      <div class="image"><span>image 3</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar-holder">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this method, but `bar` doesn't update itself once arrows/dots are clicked. I need it to be interactive

Comment: You are right, I updated the code such that the animation gets retriggered every time the playSlide method executes

Comment: Thank you for the correction. However, in some conditions, bar doesn't reset itself after an arrow/dot is clicked. Do you think it'd be possible to fix this? Or maybe any js-only method would be better?